# Download dynamic generated zip by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, zip

I want to make ZIP file by ajax and download.

in PHP(makezip.php) ZIP file is dynamically generated.

`http://exmaple.com/myzip.zip`

How can I download by javascript???

`in javascript`

```
function download(){
    $.ajax({
      url:  http://example.com/makezip.php // to Ajax
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {'id' : id}
    }).then(
        function(data) {
//How should I do here for download???
//         var blob = new Blob([ "http://exmaple.com/myzip.zip" ], { "type" : "zip" });
//         let link = document.createElement('a');
//         link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
//         link.download = 'myzipname.zip';
 //         link.click();
      }
    );
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
window.location.href = your_zip_file_path;
```

It will redirect to the next tab or it will download.